# Require all blocks found in folder (rather than write them all out)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm creating custom elements for `Visual Composer WP Plugin`. In `functions.php`, I'm referencing each block so that it loads in the admin side:

```
function vc_before_init_actions() {
    require_once('vc_elements/hero/hero.php');  
    require_once('vc_elements/text-image/text-image.php' );  
}
```

However, if I have twenty custom elements, I'll have to reference them all individually. Is there a way to just load all blocks that are in the `vc_elements` folder?

I know a potential stumbling block would be the fact that each of my `custom elements` are in different folders (i.e. hero.php is in `vc_elements > hero > hero.php`). Is it possible with my current folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code: it will require the file only if that file is in a subfolder of the path you provided to the function `requireBlockFiles` **and** the file is a PHP file **and** the folder name matches the file name (cf file `hero.php` in subfolder `hero`)

```
function requireBlockFiles($dir){
    $rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir));

    foreach ($rii as $file) {
        if ($file->isDir()){
            continue;
        }

        if(strtolower($file->getExtension()) === 'php' && $file->getPathInfo()->getFilename() . '.' . $file->getExtension() === $file->getFilename()){
            require_once($file->getPathname());
        }
    }
}

function vc_before_init_actions() {
    requireBlockFiles('vc_elements');
}
```

NOTE: this will be case sensitive for the match between folder name and file name.